# Console is intercepting all my assert messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a simple assertion macro that prints out a message. This usually works when the application is not a console application (i.e. I get a nice dialog that pops up, and has the expression including the message at which point I can hit retry to debug) but when it is, the console intercepts all the messages. This becomes annoying when the console hides behind the IDE and I have to fish it out, then go back to the assertion dialog, and hit retry to debug.

Is there any way to stop it from intercepting the messages so that the dialog that pops up has all the info.

The macro is this:

```
#define MyAssert(_Exp, _Msg) assert(_Exp && _Msg)
```

**EDIT:** Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What does the dialog look like when the console intercepts the message?

Comment: Might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111753

Comment: @Mike: I have added the screenshot

Comment: That dialog is *not* generated from your assert() call.  Your program bombed with an unhandled exception.  Use Debug + Exceptions to diagnose.

Comment: @Hans: Actually it is... I have tested it. It is due to the assert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CRT attempts to work out where you want assert output to go to based on the type of application. It detects this from the type of the executable (/SUBSYSTEM). However, you can override with _set_app_type so that the CRT acts as if your console app is a Windows app. More likely, you just want to impact assertions and so should call _CrtSetReportMode to change to _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW

You didn't specify your VS version, but these are availble (with subtle naming differences in VS2003) for all recent versions.

Martyn

Comment: The post is tagged 'visual-studio-2008' missed it myself the first time round. (+1 Didn't know about `_CrtSetReportMode`, good for know)